# how to do WHERE clause BEFORE JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

i had two tables

```
table:user
user_id   int
desc      varchar(255)


table:task
task_id        int
user_id    int
create_time datetime
```

i wanna to get count of every user whose desc="sth" on today & yesterday, so i wrote like this.

```
select u.user_id, today_task_count, yesterday_task_count
from user as u
inner join (
    select user_id,
    SUM(case when DATE(create_time) = CURDATE() then 1 else 0 end) as       today_task_count 
    SUM(case when DATE(create_time) = CURDATE()-1 then 1 else 0 end) as       yesterday_task_count
    from task
    group by user_id
) as t
On u.user_id = t.task_id
where u.desc = 'sth'
```

or

```
On u.user_id = t.task_id AND u.desc = 'sth'
```

but they  both scan all the record in table task.. 
how should i improve like this..
i know there are some question had been ask like this, but i still cannot find the solution in my scene.

=========================update============================
now i use jWeaver's anwer

```
select u.user_id, 
SUM(case when DATE(create_time) = CURDATE() then 1 else 0 end) as       today_task_count
SUM(case when DATE(create_time) = CURDATE()-1 then 1 else 0 end) as       yesterday_task_count
from (SELECT * FROM user where desc = 'sth') as u   for desc='sth' 
inner join task as t
On u.user_id = t.task_id
group by u.user_id
```

it's ok for the desc condition, but it costs 4 second, and my first sql just takes 2s to go, is the sum operation had much more pain like this?

Answer (score 0):

I think these SQL useful to you.

```
select u.user_id, count(*)
from user as u
inner join (
    select user_id
    from task
    group by user_id
) as t
On u.user_id = t.task_id
AND u.desc = 'sth' and  DATE(create_time) = CURDATE()
```

These query gives today count and yesterday count also

```
select user.user_id, today_task_count, yesterday_task_count
from
 ( SELECT * FROM user where desc = 'sth' ) as user  
 join
 ( select user_id,
    SUM(case when DATE(create_time) = CURDATE() then 1 else 0 end) as   today_task_count ,
     SUM(case when DATE(create_time) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)then 1 else 0 end) as   yesterday_task_count 
    from task
    group by user_id
   ) as task
On user.user_id = task.task_id
```

Thank you.

Comment: i just simplify the question ,i also  want  get yestoryCount

Comment: you want yester day count?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are looking for this ..

```
select u.user_id, today_task_count
from (SELECT * FROM user where desc = 'sth') as u  --- filter you table for desc='sth' 
inner join (
    select user_id,
    SUM(case when DATE(create_time) = CURDATE() then 1 else 0 end) as       today_task_count 
    from task
    group by user_id
) as t
On u.user_id = t.task_id
```

**===Update===**

```
select u.user_id, SUM(case when DATE(create_time) = CURDATE() then 1 else 0 end) as       today_task_count
    from (SELECT * FROM user where desc = 'sth') as u  --- filter you table for desc='sth' 
    inner join task as t
    On u.user_id = t.task_id
     group by u.user_id
```

Comment: i thought this may work, but it didn't , i run explain query, and it also scan all the record in task....

Comment: How do you know ? Did you check plan ? The inner queries always executes first.

Comment: i just use an not exist desc value, it runs a few second then return empty.   and explain shows the size of  all record had been scanned

Comment: See. user table will be full scanned. Since, It has to filter out the specific data. There is **no alternative** there. I thought, you were looking for something where you would like to filter out data first and then with specific data, you would like to have join with another table. In that, this is the only solution AFAIK.

Comment: task-table will be full scanned, i update the question with the explain result

Comment: If you are really concern about performance, then I would recommend to use query, which you are using currently. That will give best result in less time compare to any other query.

Comment: Obviously, It will be.

Comment: your update is fine, but if i wanna add more SUM colum like yester_task_count, it seems  every SUM operation will have much more pain for this?

Comment: Didn't get you. It will be the same for another scenario as well. Since, any how you need to sum. Right ?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why are you trying complex query for this just try this and you will get the result as required :

`select user.user_id,count(create_time) as today_task_count from task left join user on user.user_id=task.user_id 
where create_time=current_date and description="sth" group by user.user_id;`

Comment: i just simplify the question ,i also want get yesterdayCount , i comment in another answer

Comment: To include yesterday's count along with today's count you can try this:
`select user.user_id, count(case when task.create_time=current_date then 1 end) as today_task_count, count(case when task.create_time=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) then 1 end) as yesterday_task_count from task left join user on user.user_id=task.user_id where user.description="sth" group by user.user_id;`

Answer (score 0):

To include yesterday's count along with today's count you can try this 
`select user.user_id,
count(case when task.create_time=current_date then 1 end) as  today_task_count,
count(case when task.create_time=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) then 1 end) as yesterday_task_count
from task left join user on user.user_id=task.user_id 
where user.description="sth" group by user.user_id;`